# Exclude files from project in VSCode

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to exclude files/file types from the actual projects.
I only found "exclude folder from search" option in preferences.

This is especially important for Unity3D project since they have those `.meta` files for each file and folder.

Comment: Do you mean from the point of view of VSC or Unity3D editor?

Comment: From the point of view of VSC. When I open a solution with Visual Studio Code all the .meta files (and also alot of folders I do not want to be in my "coding environment" are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am happy to say that we provide this option with the next update that is soon to be announced.

**Update**

Version 0.5.0 is out and you can now exclude files and folders from the explorer and searches. The related setting is called `files.exclude` and comes with some defaults.

Comment: That would be so awesome :)

Comment: Hi! Where do we find these files.exclude settings in VS? i'm using Unity5 with VS2015 and I can choose "Exclude from Project" in VS for a folder. But the next time I open the project in VS the excluded folder is back in.

Comment: This is for VS Code, not VS!